# How to update spinner view as I type?

Tags: android, spinner

I'm making a trivia game, and would like a way for users to submit their own questions via email.

So what I have are four edittext fields, and then a Correct Answer section with a spinner. I want the user to fill out the four fields, then choose the correct answer from the spinner.

So my problem is that the spinner will not update as you type. For example, the spinner's view by default is on the 1st edit text field. But if I add a bunch of text, the spinner won't update until I click away to another item, and then come back. I would like the spinner to simply update as I type...but can't seem to figure out how to do it, although I'm sure its simple.

Here's my code:

```
    items=new String[4];
    items[0]=answer1.getText().toString();
    items[1]=answer2.getText().toString();
    items[2]=answer3.getText().toString();
    items[3]=answer4.getText().toString();


  final Spinner correctAnswerSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.answerSpinner);
  ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
  adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  correctAnswerSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

  answer1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

      }
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

      }
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          items[0]=answer1.getText().toString();
          correctAnswerSpinner.getSelectedView();
      }
  });

  answer2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      }
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
      }
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        items[1]=answer2.getText().toString();
      }
  });

  answer3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      }
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
      }
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        items[2]=answer3.getText().toString();
      }
  });

  answer4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      }
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
      }
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        items[3]=answer4.getText().toString();
      }
  });



  correctAnswerSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemSelected,
                int selectedItemPosition, long selectedId) {

                correctAnswerSpinner.setSelection(selectedItemPosition);
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }                 
    });
```

Comment: Well, nevermind. Figured it out myself. It was *very* simple. Simply add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); to tell the adapter to refresh itself.

Answer (score 0):

add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to tell the adapter to refresh itself.

Comment: Sam, I've just copied your answer to an actual "Answer" so that you can mark your question as answered.

Please answer this yourself, and then you can mark your Answer as correct in a day or two..

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will helpful to you.

Try this Code...

```
List<String> list;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Button b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    list=new ArrayList<String>();

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        list.add(ed1.getText().toString());
        list.add(ed2.getText().toString());
        ed1.setText(null);
        ed2.setText(null);
        call();
        }
        private void call() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
        adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        Spinner sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp.setAdapter(adp);
        }

    });
}
```